# Facebook not loading @font-face

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe, font-face

Is there any reason why Facebook wouldn't load

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'KomikaAxisRegular';
src: url('../komika/komikax_-webfont.eot');
src: url('../komika/komikax_-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../komika/komikax_-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../komika/komikax_-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../komika/komikax_-webfont.svg#KomikaAxisRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

It displays fine in my apache server, but the facebook page will not. I am also using git to push these changes to my facebook host maybe something might be wrong there but I can't see any reason why as everything else is updated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the underscores and dashes from the font names?

Comment: what browser are you using? I believe there is a bug in Chrome for Mac which causes this.

Comment: Are these files served via SSL?